# Any idea why my div isnt full screen

Tags: html, css, height

I was planning to make full screen sections for a page and it was all working well until it decided not to work. I am not sure what is wrong with it but if anyone could tell me I would be grateful.

Divs:

```
<div class="container1">
    <a href="#cont1">
        <img src="down.png"></img>
    </a>
    <h1>Day</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris gravida ultricies suscipit. Integer in luctus enim, id varius velit. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque feugiat lectus eget est suscipit, eget aliquam mauris pharetra. Fusce aliquet dui nec mi
        pulvinar, eu volutpat diam volutpat. Integer eget neque facilisis, ornare felis ac, vulputate eros. Etiam et accumsan erat. Aenean porttitor egestas justo et vestibulum. Donec gravida dignissim neque id vehicula. Ut non nunc ut lectus placerat tempor.
        Sed porttitor ullamcorper eros, sed eleifend felis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque mauris erat, consequat sed nulla et, volutpat accumsan leo. Mauris cursus aliquet magna, eu facilisis
        velit scelerisque vitae. Aliquam tristique id nisl in pulvinar. Vestibulum non adipiscing dui, a commodo lorem.
    </p>
</div>
<div class="container2">
    <a href="#cont">
        <img src="up.png"></img>
    </a>
    <h2>Night</h2>
    <p name=cont1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris gravida ultricies suscipit. Integer in luctus enim, id varius velit. Suspendisse potenti. Quisque feugiat lectus eget est suscipit, eget aliquam mauris pharetra. Fusce aliquet dui nec mi
        pulvinar, eu volutpat diam volutpat. Integer eget neque facilisis, ornare felis ac, vulputate eros. Etiam et accumsan erat. Aenean porttitor egestas justo et vestibulum. Donec gravida dignissim neque id vehicula. Ut non nunc ut lectus placerat tempor.
        Sed porttitor ullamcorper eros, sed eleifend felis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Quisque mauris erat, consequat sed nulla et, volutpat accumsan leo. Mauris cursus aliquet magna, eu facilisis
        velit scelerisque vitae. Aliquam tristique id nisl in pulvinar. Vestibulum non adipiscing dui, a commodo lorem.
    </p>

</div>
```

Css:

```
body {
background-image: url('http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/b8/02/64/b80264c12c88eac19d5e4c8597d051e1.jpg');
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
text-align: center;
color: white;
height: 100%;
text-shadow: black 0 0 4px;
}
p {
    height: 100%;
}
.container1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
.container2 {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://ak7.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/5200997/preview/stock-footage-blurred-background-of-moving-lights-from-a-road-of-traffic-at-night-time.jpg);
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
img {
    max-width: 15vw;
    height: auto;
}
.container1 img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.container2 img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 15vw;
}
h2{
    font-size: 15vw;
}
```

Please ignore any compatability issues or wrong use of certain tags, im working on it.

Broken Result:
[image: The site]

Im wanting the day part to be full height

Comment: Could it be because you are setting the height and width of your containers to 100%?

Comment: put your code here: jsfiddle.net, it is easier to help you that way...

Comment: So you put your broken result... what should it look it?

Comment: The full height of the window

Comment: I'm not sure if the behaviour is well defined when the combined heights of the children exceed 100% of the parent. i.e. you have an `a` element with auto height, then a `h1` element with auto height followed by a `p` element with 100% height. There is no value for the height of the div that will permit the `p` element to be the same height as the div while allowing other elements too.  Both sibling `div` elements are also set to 100% height, which is another conflict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only `body`, but `html` tag should be set to `height: 100%` as well. Percentage height property is calculated relative to the parent, and, as it turns out, `body` isn't the highest one, `html` is.

Comment: It worked so far but now the first "Day" part is slightly bigger than the screen. Am i missing something?

Comment: Try experimenting with `background-size` property

Comment: Be sure there is no `padding` on the elements that are 100%.